# is this non-essential

Tags: commas

> A. The Senate voted. The people, themselves, did not.

vs.

> B. The Senate voted. The people themselves did not.

Which one is right? A or B? Additionally, is "themselves" non-essential?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the comma(s) and "themselves" are non-essential but are used for emphasis. Ergo, both A and B are correct.

Comment: @iceguru Not a problem. Glad it was helpful.